# Returning to Remote Desktop from local desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

I'm using Remote Desktop on Windows 11 to connect to a work computer. I was able to come back to my local desktop with the Ctrl-Alt-Pause, but now I can't get back to the remote one. I can actually hear a tutorial video running from the software that just installed, but I can't get to it.

Everywhere I look tells me how to get to local from remote, but I can't find the way back anywhere.I was able to go open a new connection, so maybe it disconnected? Anyway,I kind of need to toggle back and forth and this is somewhat disconcerting.

Comment: Perhaps let it time out and then log in again.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Pause simply toggles full screen mode - have you moved the RDP window so it's off the screen maybe? or a different desktop? win+tab may help

Comment: I ended up just signing back in again. I think I've figured out how to manage the desktops now but at least I'm not lost. Thanks all.

Comment: I don't have pause button on my keyboard. I had to sign out and disconnect internet to get back to my local desktop. It only happens when you use the "All monitors" options from RDP.